# SonataMediaBundle: How to add svg file extension

Tags: php, symfony, svg, sonata-admin, sonata-media-bundle

I need to add **.svg** file extension to my configuration.

At the moment in my project I have other extensions as (pdf, images)

I made the following changes

1. Added a new svg_file to the **context**
2. Added the file provider (In the end of configuration file)
3. Added the svg in **allowed_extensions**
4. Added the image/svg+xml in **allowed_mime_types**

Now, I can upload the svg file but the problem is that the user can upload other **file extensions** for example pdf etc..

How can avoid it? Or find a proper way for the form validation?

The Sonata documentations:

- [ADVANCED CONFIGURATION](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/master/doc/reference/advanced_configuration.html)
- [Media context](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/master/doc/reference/media_context.html)

helped me, but not for the form validation.

What I'm missing?

---

I changed the follows files:

```
#app/config/sonata_config.yml

sonata_media:
default_context: images_file
db_driver: doctrine_orm # or doctrine_mongodb, doctrine_phpcr
contexts:
    pdf_file:
        providers:
            - sonata.media.provider.file
        formats: ~
    images_file:
        providers:
            - sonata.media.provider.image
        formats:
            1x: { width: 870 , height: 412 , quality: 80 }
            2x: { width: 1740 , height: 824 , quality: 50 }
    svg_file:
        providers:
            - sonata.media.provider.file
        formats: ~
    cdn:
        server:
          path: /uploads/media # http://media.sonata-project.org/

    filesystem:
        local:
           directory:  %kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/media
           create:     false

    providers:
        file:
           service:    sonata.media.provider.file
           resizer:    false
           filesystem: sonata.media.filesystem.local
           cdn:        sonata.media.cdn.server
           generator:  sonata.media.generator.default
           thumbnail:  sonata.media.thumbnail.format
           allowed_extensions: ['pdf', 'txt', 'rtf', 'doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'ppt', 'pttx', 'odt', 'odg', 'odp', 'ods', 'odc', 'odf', 'odb', 'csv', 'xml','svg']
           allowed_mime_types: ['application/pdf', 'application/x-pdf', 'application/rtf', 'text/html', 'text/rtf', 'text/plain', 'image/svg+xml']
```

Form File:

```
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
class CustomAdmin extends Admin
{
/**
 * @param FormMapper $formMapper
 */
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add(
            'NormalLogo',
            'sonata_type_model_list',
            array('required' => false),
            array(
                'link_parameters' => array('context' => 'images_file', 'provider' => 'sonata.media.provider.image'),
            )
        )
        ->add(
            'SvgLogo',
            'sonata_type_model_list',
            array('required' => false),
            array(
                'link_parameters' => array('context' => 'svg_file', 'provider' => 'sonata.media.provider.file'),
            )
        )
        ->add('overriddenBy', 'sonata_type_model',
            array(
                'empty_value' => 'Not overridden',
                'btn_add' => false,
                'btn_list' => false,
                'btn_delete' => false,
                'btn_catalogue' => false,
            )
        );
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own provider for SVG files only to do this you need to define a service first for your SVG provider

```
parameters:
    application_sonata_media.svg_class: Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Provider\SVGProvider
services:
    sonata.media.provider.svg:
          class: %application_sonata_media.svg_class%
          tags:
              - { name: sonata.media.provider }
          arguments:
              - sonata.media.provider.svg
              - @sonata.media.filesystem.local
              - @sonata.media.cdn.server
              - @sonata.media.generator.default
              - @sonata.media.thumbnail.format
              - allowed_extensions: ['svg']
              - allowed_mime_types: ['image/svg+xml']
```

Using sonata you can generate extended bundles using [`EASYEXTENDS BUNDLE`](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/easy-extends/master/doc/index.html) by default it generates extended bundle in `src/Application/Sonata/MediaBundle` but you can specify other destination as well.Now create above service in extended media bundle's `services.yml` and import in main `config.yml`.If you want to add more mime types or extensions you can define in above service `allowed_mime_types: ['image/svg+xml','application/pdf']`

```
imports:
    - { resource: @ApplicationSonataMediaBundle/Resources/config/services.yml }
```

Now create your provider class in your  extended media bundle as `SVGProvider` and extend your provider class with sonata media's `FileProvider`

```
<?php
namespace Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Provider;

use Sonata\MediaBundle\Provider\FileProvider as BaseFileProvider;
use Gaufrette\Filesystem;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Validator\ErrorElement;
use Sonata\MediaBundle\CDN\CDNInterface;
use Sonata\MediaBundle\Generator\GeneratorInterface;
use Sonata\MediaBundle\Metadata\MetadataBuilderInterface;
use Sonata\MediaBundle\Model\MediaInterface;
use Sonata\MediaBundle\Thumbnail\ThumbnailInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotNull;

class SVGProvider extends BaseFileProvider {
    protected $allowedMimeTypes;
    protected $allowedExtensions;
    protected $metadata;

    public function __construct( $name, Filesystem $filesystem, CDNInterface $cdn, GeneratorInterface $pathGenerator, ThumbnailInterface $thumbnail, array $allowedExtensions = array(), array $allowedMimeTypes = array(), MetadataBuilderInterface $metadata = null ) {
        parent::__construct( $name, $filesystem, $cdn, $pathGenerator, $thumbnail );

        $this->allowedExtensions = $allowedExtensions;
        $this->allowedMimeTypes  = $allowedMimeTypes;
        $this->metadata          = $metadata;
    }

    public function buildCreateForm( FormMapper $formMapper ) {
        $formMapper->add( 'binaryContent', 'file', array(
            'label'       => 'Upload SVG file only',
            'constraints' => array(
                new NotBlank(),
                new NotNull(),
            ),
        ) );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function validate( ErrorElement $errorElement, MediaInterface $media ) {

        if ( ! $media->getBinaryContent() instanceof \SplFileInfo ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( $media->getBinaryContent() instanceof UploadedFile ) {
            $fileName = $media->getBinaryContent()->getClientOriginalName();
        } elseif ( $media->getBinaryContent() instanceof File ) {
            $fileName = $media->getBinaryContent()->getFilename();
        } else {
            throw new \RuntimeException( sprintf( 'Invalid binary content type: %s', get_class( $media->getBinaryContent() ) ) );
        }

        if ( ! in_array( strtolower( pathinfo( $fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) ), $this->allowedExtensions ) ) {
            $errorElement
                ->with( 'binaryContent' )
                ->addViolation( 'Invalid extensions' )
                ->end();
        }

        if ( ! in_array( $media->getBinaryContent()->getMimeType(), $this->allowedMimeTypes ) ) {
            $errorElement
                ->with( 'binaryContent' )
                ->addViolation( 'Invalid mime type : ' . $media->getBinaryContent()->getMimeType() )
                ->end();
        }
    }
}
```

Here you can override base class functions and define your own functionality as you wish for example you want to add some validations to file input you can customize `validate()` function to change attributes for file input field you can define it in `buildCreateForm()` method

Now in your admin if you want to allow only SVG to upload you can define your own provider which allows only SVG files

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add(
            'SvgLogo',
            'sonata_type_model_list',
            array('required' => false),
            array(
                'link_parameters' => array('context' => 'svg_file', 'provider' => 'sonata.media.provider.svg'),
            )
        )
}
```

Comment: Still a valid solution, thank you. I adapted it a little and it can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/kunicmarko20/0af5e61510a68706ecbf658c0c690b8a).